# how to change mode Grid in backend

Tags: magento2, admin, order-grid

i would like to know if anybody has already change the mode of grid.

By defaut, in list of orders, we have this mode :

[image]

is it possible to get this display :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you cannot change this "on the fly".
What you have there are 2 types of grids with 2 different implementations.
The second on is the "new trend" grid that you can find in the products list, customers, cms pages and blocks and a few other entities and are implemented via ui-components.
You can see how it is [defined in here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_listing.xml)
The second one is the "old version" that still exists for a few modules but you should not use that one.
You can see an example in the [backup module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Backup/view/adminhtml/layout/backup_index_block.xml).
This one does not use ui-components. It's just a simple layout file with block definitions inside it.